# Что означает режим совместимости SQL в импорте phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Что означает "режим совместимости SQL" в разделе импорта phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @cheops  Они в в самой  панеле "Импорт"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что несмотря на то, что SQL является единым языком запросов реляционных баз данных и для него существует стандарт, фактически каждая СУБД реализует свой диалект SQL. Кто-то еще не реализовал стандарт определенного уровня, а их несколько, кто-то уже вперед убежал и запилил то, что в стандарте еще и в помине нет, а может и не появится вообще.

Поэтому если берете SQL-дамп созданный средствами одной базы данных и импортируете в MySQL у вас могут возникнуть трудности с ключевыми словами или синтаксисом, который MySQL не поддерживает или реализует немного иначе. Именно для этого, существуют режимы совместимости, которые позволяют скорректировать SQL-дамп при импорте, чтобы выполнить его без предварительного преобразования. В списке указываются названия СУБД, чьи дампы вы можете попробовать импортировать (это не всегда возможно, так как во многих СУБД реализованы особенности, вообще не поддерживаемые MySQL).